# Missing keyboard shortcut in El Capitan 10.11.5 to switch between windows within app

Tags: keyboard, macos, switching

I've just started running El Capitan (10.11.5) and one of my favorite keyboard shortcuts seems to have disappeared: the keyboard shortcut that let you move between windows within the same application. It used to be  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>   (tilde) but now that shortcut doesn't work and I can't figure out how to get it back.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that's a 'backtick', not a tilde - that's the accent that goes over the n in mañana... on its own, ~

Answer (score 1):

The `Keyboard` item in `System Preferences` has a `Shortcuts` tab. The `Keyboard` item in the `Shortcuts` tab has one item labeled `Move focus to next window`. The binding for that has a  <kbd>`</kbd>   rather than a  <kbd>~</kbd>   (with the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key; I don't know how to type a cloverleaf), but either binding has the same effect for me (that box is checked on my Mac).

It's possible you simply need to check that box; in any case, that seems like the first place to look.

Comment: I changed the commands to 'Ask Different standard' & added the cover-leaf for you :) I actually have it as a shortcut in System Prefs > Keyboard > Text [I also have the Ask Different standard key command syntax in there] Check my edit to see how it's done

Comment: I appreciate the assistance with my answer. Thanks!